# Creating attendance in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Well.. I have created a attendance system for salesman and structure of my database is

1. **users** (id, name)
2. **attendances**(att_id, user_id, created_at)

This is the data that I have and used in creating the attendance,

```
$final = array:2 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
"id" => 6
"name" => "Talha Munshi"
"attendance" => array:4 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "attendance" => "P"
    "advance" => "0"
    "date" => Carbon {#250 ▼
      +"date": "2017-07-16 08:07:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
    }
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "attendance" => "P"
    "advance" => "0"
    "date" => Carbon {#249 ▼
      +"date": "2017-07-17 08:07:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
    }
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "attendance" => "A"
    "advance" => "0"
    "date" => Carbon {#248 ▼
      +"date": "2017-07-18 08:07:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
    }
   ]
   3 => array:3 [▼
    "attendance" => "L"
    "advance" => "0"
    "date" => Carbon {#241 ▼
      +"date": "2017-07-19 08:07:00.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "Asia/Karachi"
        }  
      ]
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▶]
]

$days_count = 20; //From first till today (20th)
```

Now, I tried a bit of coding to populate each day's attendance in vertical format and the code written in view is this :

```
<table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Salesman</td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $days_count; $i++){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php }?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($final as $attend)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $attend['name'] }}</td>
                <?php for($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++){
                    $make_date = date("Y-m")."-".$i;
                ?>

                <?php foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){ 
                    if($att['date'] == $make_date){
                ?>
                <td><?php echo $att['attendance']; ?></td>
                <?php } else{?> <td>-</td> <?php  } }?>
                <?php }?>
            </tr>
            @empty
            <tr><td>No Salesman</td></tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it just gave answer that literally squashed my brain. This below is the current result

[image]

Could anyone help me out with this please ?

I made the `$final` array through this.

```
$users = User::select('id', 'name')
        ->where('type','LIKE','salesman')
        ->get();
$attendances = Attendance::whereBetween('created_at', [$first_date, $now])
        ->get();
foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $salesman['id'] = $user->id;
        $salesman['name'] = $user->name;

        foreach($attendances as $attendance)
        {
            if($attendance->user_id == $user->id)
            {
                $attend_2['attendance'] = $attendance->attendance;
                $attend_2['advance'] = $attendance->advance;
                $attend_2['date'] = $attendance->created_at;
                $attend[] = $attend_2;
            }

        }
        $salesman['attendance'] = $attend;
        $final[] = $salesman;
    }
```

Required Output: what it should be

[image]

Comment: So whats Problem There?

Comment: Why are you using `@forelse` ? does it should be `@foreach` ?

Comment: Look at the current output! All dashes! It should write "P" or "A" or "L" in the matching days.

Comment: It should add attendance on 16, 17, 18, and 19

Comment: Added an output sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the view to:

```
<table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Salesman</td>
      <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $days_count; $i++){ ?>
      <td>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
      </td>
      <?php }?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @forelse($final as $attend)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $attend['name'] }}</td>
      <?php 
        for($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++){
          $make_date = date("Y-m")."-".$i;
          $set_attendance_for_day=false;
          $attendance_for_day ="-";
          foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){
            if($att['date'] == $make_date){
               $attendance_for_day = "P";
            } 
          } 
      ?>
      <td>
        <?php echo $attendance_for_day; ?>
      </td>

      <?php }?>
    </tr>
    @empty
    <tr>
      <td>No Salesman</td>
    </tr>
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> What if I had to insert a form on the last date i.e 20. How can I do that?

Then use:

```
<table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Salesman</td>
      <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $days_count; $i++){ ?>
      <td>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
      </td>
      <?php }?>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @forelse($final as $attend)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $attend['name'] }}</td>
      <?php 
        for($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++){
          $make_date = date("Y-m")."-".$i;
          $set_attendance_for_day=false;
          $attendance_for_day ="-";
          foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){
            if($att['date'] == $make_date){
               $attendance_for_day = "P";
            } 
          } 
      ?>
      <td>
        <?php echo $attendance_for_day; ?>
        <?php if($i==20){ ?>

          ---------------------------------------------------
          <PLACE YOUR FORM HERE>
          ---------------------------------------------------
        <?php } ?>
      </td>

      <?php }?>
    </tr>
    @empty
    <tr>
      <td>No Salesman</td>
    </tr>
    @endforelse
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! What if I had to insert a form on the last date i.e 20. How can I do that?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is this block

```
<?php foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){ 
if($att['date'] == $make_date){
?>
<td><?php echo $att['attendance']; ?></td>
<?php } else{?> <td>-</td> <?php  } }?>
<?php }?>
```

You are comparing a date with the format Y-m-d with a Carbon date that was set with `$attend_2['date'] = $attendance->created_at;`

To fix this, you can format the Carbon date before setting it in your array: `$attend_2['date'] = $attendance->created_at->format( 'Y-m-d');`

The second problem is that you have for loop over the days and inside that loop, you are looping over each attendance. That is why there are so many - characters. A simple fix to this is to set a flag if the attendance is present and then check that flag outside the inside loop:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++){
    $make_date = date("Y-m")."-".$i;
    $set_attendance_for_day=false;
    foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){
        if($att['date'] == $make_date){
            $set_attendance_for_day=true;
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $att['attendance']; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if (!$set_attendance_for_day) { ?>
        <td>-</td>
    <?php } ?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Well.. it shows right number of blocks but still doesn't echo P A or L on the right spots

Answer (score 1):

I think you have problem with the date comparison in the following line.

```
 if($att['date'] == $make_date){

 }
```

Here, `$make_date` will give you date something like `2017-07-20` and you are trying to compare with Carbon `DateTime` like `2017-07-20 04:55:09` This will never equal.

So, you have to format `$att['date']` with Carbon.

Like this:

```
if($att['date']->format('Y-m-d') == $make_date){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would search if the date is present in the attendance and print accordingly

```
@forelse($final as $attend)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $attend['name'] }}</td>
    @for ($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++)
    {{--*/ $make_date = Carbon\Carbon::create(date("Y-m")."-".$i); /*--}}
    {{--*/ $key = array_search($make_date, array_column($attend['attendance'], 'date')); /*--}}
    @if ($key !== FALSE)
        <td>{{ $att['attendance'][$key]['attendance'] }}</td>
    @else
        <td>-</td>
    @endif
    @endfor
</tr>
@empty
<tr><td>No Salesman</td></tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Remove extra loop. Create flag variable and check it.

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < $days_count; $i++){
    $make_date = date("Y-m")."-".$i;
    $set_attendance_for_day=false;
    foreach($attend['attendance'] as $att){
        if($att['date'] == $make_date){
            $set_attendance_for_day=true;
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $att['attendance']; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if (!$set_attendance_for_day) { ?>
        <td>-</td>
    <?php } 
       else{ ?>
        <td>P</td>
    <?php  }
    ?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks! What if I had to insert a form on the last date i.e 20. How can I do that?

Comment: Form like  each <td> would have input with name="id[]" and select name="attendance[]"

Comment: Sorry can't understand what are you asking

Answer (score 0):

```
    > Controller
      public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request,[
               'input_date' => 'required',
            ]);
    
            $month = date('m',strtotime($request->input_date));
            $year = date('Y',strtotime($request->input_date));
    
            $all_user = User::all();
    
            $days_in_input_month =  cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
            $array=[];
    
            foreach ( $all_user as $user){
                $user_id = $user->id;
                $user_name = $user->name;
                $array[$user_id]=[];
                for ( $i =1 ; $i<=$days_in_input_month ; $i++){
                    $date = date('d-m-Y',strtotime($i.'-'.$month.'-'.$year));
    
                    $user_attendance = attendance::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
                    $flag = 0 ;
                    foreach ($user_attendance as $single_attendance){
                        $user_attendance_date =  date('d-m-Y',strtotime($single_attendance->date));
                        if( $date== $user_attendance_date){
                            $flag=1;
                        }
                    }
                    $array[$user_id][] = $flag;
                }
            }
          return view('attendance',[
              'attendance_data' => $array,
              'total_day' =>$days_in_input_month,
              'date' => $request->input_date
          ]) ;
    
        }
    >blade
 <h2>Month: {{ date('M, Y',strtotime( $date)) }}</h2>
                        @if($attendance_data )
                            <table class="table-responsive table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User Name</th>
                                   @for($i=1 ; $i<=$total_day;$i++)
                                       <th>{{ $i }}</th>
                                       @endfor
                                </tr>

                                   @foreach($attendance_data as $key => $value )

                                       <td>{{\App\Models\User::where('id',$key)->get()[0]['name'] }}</td>
                                       @foreach($value as $item2)
                                           <td>{{ $item2=='0' ? '-': 'P' }}</td>
                                       @endforeach
                                       </tr>
                                   @endforeach


                            </table>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        @endif
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain what you did here.