# Creating attendance report in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My question is very similar to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205142/creating-attendance-in-laravel) and almost my code is copied from this. But the problem is it cannot display the "P" letter and "H" if the staff is present or if the date is holiday. (I try most of the answer from above link)

Controller

```
$report = Report::findOrFail($id);
$staffs = Staff::where('building_id', $report->building_id)->get();
$month = date('m', strtotime($report->data));
$attendances = [];

foreach ($staffs as $staff) {
  $holidays = Holiday::whereMonth('date', $month)->get();
  $month_in_no = date('m', strtotime($report->data));
  $s = Staff::where('id', $staff->id)->with(['attendance' => function($attend) use ($month_in_no) {
              $attend->whereMonth('date', $month_in_no)->where('direction', 'In');
  }])->get();
  array_push($attendances, $s);
}
```

And my Blade file

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($attendances as $attendance)
    @foreach ($attendance as $staff)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $staff->name }}</td>
            @php $totalPresentCount = 0 @endphp
            @for ($i = 1; $i < $daysInMonth; $i++)
                @php
                    $date_create = date('Y-m')."-".$i;
                    $pre_abs = '-';
                @endphp
                @foreach ($staff->attendance as $att)
                    @foreach ($holidays as $holiday)
                        @php
                            $date_to_check = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($att->date));
                        @endphp
                        @if ($date_create == $date_to_check) {{-- cannot check here for my notice! but don't know why --}}
                            @php
                                $pre_abs = 'P';
                                $totalPresentCount++;
                            @endphp
                        @elseif ($date_to_check == $holiday->date || date('D', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $report->year)) == 'Sat' || date('D', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $report->year)) == 'Sun')
                            @php
                                $pre_abs = 'H';
                            @endphp
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
                <td>{{ $pre_abs }}</td>
            @endfor

            {{-- below is for checking total p/a/h --}}
            <td>{{ $totalPresentCount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $daysInMonth - count($holidays) - $totalPresentCount }}</td>
            <td>{{ count($holidays) }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

It can shows the output like below

[image]

how to show the "P" letter if the staff is present in that particular day and "H" if the date is in `Holiday::model()`

Thanks in advance

Comment: On quick comment (that might not be the solution to the whole problem, but at least will solve another one). You use `$date_create = date('Y-m')."-".$i;` to create a date and later you compare that with a date created like `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($att->date));`. The first method would result in a date like for example `2020-01-1` but your second used method would create a date like `2020-01-01`. These will never match, although it represents the same day.

Comment: so should I use leading zero in `$date_create`

Comment: You could take a look at the strpad() function. Another (more work, but better practice) way is to start using the DateTime object instead of the procedural date() function. This way when you can create DateTime objects using `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-01-01')` or `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2020-01-1')`the results will be the same. You can then format this date back to a string using e.g. `$date->format('Y-m-d');`.

Comment: I think maybe there is another bug too. because `date('Y-m')` returns day year and month of today, but  `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($att->date))` returns date of the attend date. if the year and month were different(like your example), these two dates don't equal. You can fix it easily with just some print in your code.

Comment: Now I used `$date_create = date('Y-m')."-".sprintf("%02d", $i);` and it return like `2020-01-01`

Comment: @Raftx24 I concatenate `$i` and I don't think there is an error

Comment: the problem is that date_create is for example `2020-05-05` and attend date is `2020-02-05`, I encourage you add this to your code to find out the problem  `{{$date_create .'== '. $date_to_check}}`

Comment: yeah, right.. before it check `2020-05-01` current month.. now I put `$date_create = $report->year ."-".$month."-".sprintf("%02d", $i);` and the "P" letter is shown in the blade file. but the Holiday is still a problem

Comment: I check the wrong date for Holiday to represent "H", but now it's fixed